# How does compareTo work?

Tags: java, equals, comparable, compareto

I know that `compareTo` returns a negative or positive result on how well one string correlates to the other, but then why:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String y = "ab2";
        if(y.compareTo("ac3") == -1) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

is true and

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String y = "ab2";
        if(y.compareTo("ab3") == -1) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

is also true?

Comment: Don't use `==-1` but `<0`. Notice that `"ab2".compareTo("cb2")` returns -2, just like `"ab2".compareTo("ab4")` (result is difference in Unicode Table of character which are different in string indexes - if length of strings is same).

Comment: Comparison using `compareTo` does not use correlation: correlation is a symmetric property, whereas `compareTo` is (or at least should be) anti-symmetric, at least in the sense that `sign(a.compareTo(b)) = -sign(b.compareTo(a))`.

Answer (score 19):

The general contract of [`Comparable.compareTo(o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is to return

- a positive integer if this is greater than the other object.
- a negative integer if this is lower than the other object.
- 0 if this is equals to the other object.

In your example `"ab2".compareTo("ac3") == -1` and `"ab2".compareTo("ab3") == -1` **only means** that `"ab2"` is lower than both `"ac3"` and `"ab3"`. You cannot conclude anything regarding `"ac3"` and `"ab3"` with only these examples.

This result is expected since `b` comes before `c` in the alphabet (so `"ab2" < "ac3"`) and `2` comes before `3` (so `"ab2" < "ab3"`): Java sorts Strings [lexicographically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-).

Comment: It is important to know that "ab7" would still be smaller than "ac2" even though the last integer suggests ab7 should be greater than ac2 because the compareTo() lexicographically works as follows:-    If Strings are different then take the least index where it differs in our example "ab7" and "ac2" the least index is 1(even though index 2 also differs!) and in that index see the lexicographical order (b is smaller than c) hence "ab7" is smaller to "ac2".

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` for `String`s returns -1 if the first `String` (the one for which the method is called) comes before the second `String` (the method's argument) in lexicographical order. "ab2" comes before "ab3" (since the first two characters are equal and 2 comes before 3) and also before "ac3" (since the first character is equal and b comes before c), so both comparisons return -1.

Comment: More precisely: compareTo for Strings returns _a negative number_ if the first String comes before the second String

Answer (score 1):

compareTo() compares two string with regard to their alphabetical order. Both of you tests have a String that is alphabetically sorted "before" the String you compare it with. In other words:

- ab2 < ac3 (because b < c)
- ab2 < ab3 (because 2 < 3)

By the way, you should rather use "< 0" than "== -1" in your if statement, as the `compareTo` spec says that the function returns a negative number, not specifically "-1"