# How do I create an if statement in Java that throws an error if the sum of two text fields is greater than another textfield

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java and I have three text fields which are all integers in my Java project.
I want to create an if statement that throws an error if the sum of values in text field 1 and 2 are greater than textfield 3.
This is what I was able to come up with

```
if (text3.getText() > (text1.getText()+text2.getText())){
    System.out.println(“Error”)
}
```

Do I need to put it in a try and catch statement?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does compareTo work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443402/how-does-compareto-work)

Comment: Hint: you should almost certainly be parsing those strings into integers, otherwise the addition and comparison won't make much sense.

Comment: @Olaf Kock no it doesn’t.

Comment: @Jon Skeet like this “Integer.parseInt(field1)”?

Comment: Well, in that you'd be calling `Integer.parseInt`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create yourself a new `Exception` Class:

```
public class NumberExceededException extends Exception {
    public NumberExceededException(String exceptionMessage){
        super(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

Then use it with:

```
If (text3.getText() > (text1.getText()+text2.getText())) {
    throw new NumberExceededException("You have exceeded my expectations");
}
```

This will throw a new bubbling exception which can be caught by a try catch higher up.

Just to note that this is not exclusive to Netbeans it is a Java function, Netbeans is an IDE and only outputs whatever the JVM tells it to output.

Comment: I got an error when I tried this:  "public class NumberExceededException extends Exception {
    public NumberExceededException(String exceptionMessage){
        super(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
    try{
    If (Container_Num.getText() > (size20.getText()+size40.getText())){
    throw new NumberExceededException("You have exceeded it");
    }
    catch (NumberExceededException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Integral_F.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}"

Comment: If you are going to use a nested class it has to be inside the java class but not inside a method. I would recommend however making the exception its own java file then importing it and using it that way, it's better than nesting classes.